# Extend applicability of \qedhere to theorem-class elements

Tags: amsthm

**Goal:** I want to be able to mark the end of examples and exercises using some sort of symbol, much as $\qedsymbol$ marks the end of proofs. In particular, I want a command that acts like \qedhere for my symbol of choice.

**Background:** This is in fact one of the potential modifications listed in the [amsthm package documentation](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf): to "extend applicability of \qedhere to theorem-class elements as well as to proofs." They say that while this has merit, it requires more work and is essentially on the back burner.

**My attempt:**

The way I have attempted to implement an exercise environment with its own end-symbol is as follows:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[varg,bigdelims]{newpxmath}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{madesymbol}

\newtheorem{exc}{Exercise}
\newcounter{exc-counter}
\newenvironment{exercise}[1][]
{
    \begin{exc}[#1]~
    \def\mysymbol{$\lozenge$}
    \setcounter{madesymbol}{0}
    \def\tagsymbol{\stepcounter{madesymbol}\tag*{\mysymbol}}
}
{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{madesymbol}}{0}}{\hspace*{\fill}\mysymbol}{}
    \end{exc}
    \stepcounter{exc-counter}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
A function $f$...
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

This feels bulky, and I'm looking for a better solution.

**Problems with ntheorem:**
One suggestion I have seen is the ntheorem package. I have tried ntheorem, but it seems to change "everything", e.g. not act at all like amsthm (even with the [amsthm] option loaded). If someone suggests I use this package, please give explicit code for making it act as much like amsthm as possible.

Comment: Could you add a MWE with a definition of `\lozenge`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}

\newtheorem{ex-inner}{Exercise}
\newenvironment{ex}{%
  %\def\qedsymbol{$\lozenge$}% Set the QED symbol. 
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \begin{ex-inner}%
}{%
  \popQED
  \end{ex-inner}%
}


\begin{ex}
Here is an exercise.
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
Hi!
\[x=y\qedhere\]
\end{ex}

\begin{proof}
Hi!
\[x=y\qedhere\]
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: if you add `\usepackage{amssymb}`, `\lozenge` will be available.  (i'd need to check more carefully, but i'm pretty sure this is essentially how the enhancement would be made to `amsthm`.  good going.)

Comment: This is great, thanks Hood. By the way, what's the value of all the %-signs, and why not put one after \popQED ?

Comment: Tex by default converts a single new line character into a space, two newlines in a row into a `\par`. The `%` at the end of the line prevents tex from putting a space there. After a control sequence, tex is in ignoring spaces mode so no percent is necessary.

Comment: These `%`'s are very typical in tex code because newlines are good for code readability and it's generally undesirable for them to change the output.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demo of how it can be done with `ntheorem`. One distinctive feature is that the placement is automatic, even with therems ending in a multiline display (it may require two compilations, and there must be no blank line at the end of the environment. The QED symbol is quite easy to customise:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\usepackage[thmmarks, thref, amsmath]{ntheorem}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape\bfseries}% default is \upshape\bfseries
\theoremseparator{. \textemdash}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]

\theoremseparator{.}
\theoremheaderfont{\upshape\bfseries}%
\theorembodyfont{\upshape\mdseries}% default is \itshape
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}[section]
\theoremsymbol{\raisebox{-0.1\height}{\color{IndianRed}$ \boldsymbol\diamondsuit $}}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}

\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
\theoremseparator{:}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\color{Gainsboro}\blacksquare}}

\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2}

\begin{thm}
Clangle-Wangles’ habits of life are domestic and superfluous, and their general demeanour pensive and pellucid.
\end{thm}

\begin{dfn}
  A \textbf{Snark} is a Boojum.
\end{dfn}

\begin{ex}
Here is an exercise.
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
Hi!
\[ x=y \]
\end{ex}

\begin{proof}
There are two cases: \useshortskip
\begin{align*}
x & =y \\ u & =v
\end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]